# How to properly pass in data to map method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to add a marker to Google maps. I will trace back beginning with the root `index.ts` file:

```
import { rawData } from "./csvFileReader";
import { Address } from "./Address";

import { CustomMap } from "./CustomMap";

const ROW_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

// console.log(data);

const data: Address[] = [];

// const rawRow = data.toString();
// const address = new Address(rawData);

for (const rawRow of rawData.split(ROW_DELIMITER)) {
  data.push(new Address(rawRow));
}

console.log(data);

// const address = data;

// console.log(address);

// console.log(new Address(data.toString()));

const customMap = new CustomMap("map");
customMap.addAddressMarker();
```

This imports the `csvFileReader` so I do not have to duplicate all over the place:

```
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

export const rawData = readFileSync("src/Cales_trim_down.csv", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});
```

It's also importing the `Address` class:

```
import { rawData } from "./csvFileReader";

export class Address {
  Address: string;
  // General_Plan_Designation: string;
  Latitude: number;
  Longitude: number;

  static DELIMITER = ",";

  constructor(rawRow: string) {
    const data = rawRow.split(Address.DELIMITER);

    this.Address = data[0];
    // this.General_Plan_Designation = data[1];
    this.Latitude = parseFloat(data[2]);
    this.Longitude = parseFloat(data[3]);
  }
}

const ROW_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

const data: Address[] = [];

for (const rawRow of rawData.split(ROW_DELIMITER)) {
  data.push(new Address(rawRow));
}
```

This is my `CustomMap` class:

```
import { Address } from "./Address";

export class CustomMap {
  private googleMap: google.maps.Map;

  constructor(divId: string) {
    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(divId), {
      zoom: 1,
      center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
      },
    });
  }

  addAddressMarker(address: Address): void {
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.googleMap,
      position: {
        lat: address.Latitude,
        lng: address.Longitude,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

I am successfully getting a google map, but where I need help on is how to take that `data` property and pass it in `customMap.addAddressMarker();`

These are the different ways I have tried:

```
// console.log(new Address(data.toString()));
```

Comment: `data.forEach(address => customMap.addAddressMarker(address))`?

Comment: @rveerd, perfect.